# Open HTML editor from Firefox

Tags: firefox, html

(Ubuntu 17.04, Firefox 53.0)

I have my Firefox Homepage set to a local HTML file with links to various local files/folders I need to work on, e.g. `file:///home/user/path/to/local/folder`.

I can use Firefox to navigate the folders and for file formats that Firefox cannot open, Firefox opens an `Open with...` dialogue that allows me to open the file straight from Firefox.

However, for HTML files, Firefox just displays the content (as a browser should). Is there a way to open the HTML editor (e.g. gedit) straight from Firefox? (Or a way to tell Firefox to open Nautilus instead of opening the folder in Firefox?)

Comment: I don't know if there is a direct way, but you could open the page source (Ctrl+u) and save that as a .txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the view Page Source configuration by following these steps:

1. Visit `about:config` in your Firefox web browser.
2. Paste `view_source.editor.external` into the search bar and change the value from false to true by double-clicking on it.
3. Paste `view_source.editor.path` into the search bar and right-click on the value to modify it. A dialogue box will appear. Set the path to your desired editor (`/usr/bin/gedit` for Gedit) and click *OK*.
4. Now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or *Page Source* to open the editor.

Comment: Woah, learned something new late at night. +1.